# Attaining only minimum value from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm iterating through a dictionary with the names of presidents as the key for my dictionary and a tuple containing the year inaugurated, years served, age at start of term and what state they were from. In this instance I'm just looking at the age they started their term for this. Sample of the dictonary:

```
pres_data={"Reagan": (1981, 8, 69,"California"), "Bush":(1989, 4,64,"Texas")}
```

The dictionary goes through more of President and data like above, but I'm not including it since it would be too much to put on here.

The output I'm looking for is :

```
(64,["George Bush"])
```

So it'll display the minimum age first ( which I'm assuming will use a min() function to get that, but it hasn't worked in my set up just yet) and then followed by a list of President names that share that youngest age from that dictionary.

My code so far:

```
pres_data={"Reagan": (1981, 8, 69,"California"), "Bush":(1989,4,64,"Texas")}
for key, value in pres_data.items():
    age_start_term=value[2]
    print(age_start_term,key)
```

I was thinking of placing something like youngest= min(age_start_term) after my age_start_term variable, but that would only check for that one iteration. So I guess I'm looking to both get the minimum comparison to happen and print alongside a list containing the keys that go along with the youngest age represented in the dictionary. 
What could I add to what I have in order to get it to compare all the ages once I iterate through? And to get the keys that correspond to the youngest age in the dictionary , could I do something along these lines?

```
allyoungest= [k for k in pres_data if pres_data[k] == #variable representing youngest]
```

Answer (score 6):

The `min` function takes an argument called `key` which you can use to extract a comparison key from the items you're trying to compare. In your case, something like:

```
youngest = min(pres_data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2])
```

This will give you:

```
('Bush', (1989, 4, 64, 'Texas'))
```

which you should be able to turn into whatever output format you want.

If you want a list of all presidents with the same minimum age, you can just do another pass, as you surmised:

```
min_age = youngest[1][2]
all_youngest = [name for name in pres_data if pres_data[name][2] == min_age]
```

Answer (score 2):

A functional way to go about it:

```
from functools import reduce

pres_data = {"Reagan": (1981, 8, 69,"California"), "Bush":(1989,4,64,"Texas")}

def min_pres(acc, it):
    min_age, presidents = acc
    name, (year, served, age, state) = it

    if min_age is None or age < min_age:
        return (age, [name])

    elif age == min_age:
        presidents.append(name)

    return acc

reduce(min_pres, pres_data.items(), (None, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Temptation is to use min, but that requires iterating through the list at least once, and then you also have to build some index on age during start of the term.  A better option would be to build a dictionary of age at start term to a president, and as you build keep track of the min age.  Then you just need to reference which entries matched that index.

```
import collections

pres_data = {
    "Reagan": (1981, 8, 69,"California"),
    "Bush": (1989,4,64,"Texas"),
    "LizardKing": (2569,4,64,"Nrzilplack")
}

bday_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

min_age = 1000
for key, value in pres_data.items():
    age_start_term = value[2]
    if age_start_term < min_age:
        min_age = age_start_term

    bday_dict[age_start_term].append(key)

print(min_age, bday_dict[min_age])
# 64 ['LizardKing', 'Bush']
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
sorted(pres_data.items(), key= lambda x: x[1][2])[0]
```

Comment: This would be `O(n log n)` as opposed to an `O(n)` using min and you still use a lambda so I cannot see the logic in using sorted.

Comment: Your are right. It was my fault not to read question as a whole :)